# Passing Azure Release Info to Jira Issue

Tags: azure-devops, jira, jira-rest-api

I have recently migrated the work items to Jira Cloud. I am using Azure Devops for my releases.
I want to use Jira API to update the issue once the release is completed. My issues contains a release info field which I want to update with my Release number in Azure DevOps
[image]

I read Jira API documentation from - https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/7.3.1/
but couldn't get a clue updating an issue field.
Also tried to understand https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/updating-an-issue-via-the-jira-rest-apis-6848604/ still couldn't get what I am looking for.

Is there any other option/ API which I am missing. Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This blog: [Azure Pipelines integration with Jira Software](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-pipelines-integration-with-jira-software/), mentions that you can install [Azure Pipelines integration with Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220515/azure-pipelines-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) and connect Azure DevOps organizations with your Jira Software instance. So you can follow this tutorial: [Integrate with Jira Issue tracking](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-jira/blob/master/tutorial.md) to report deployment status to Jira issues.
[image]